# Finding Positive Integer Solutions to $(b+c)^2 - b^2 c = 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all positive integer solutions to $(b+c)^2 - b^2 c = 1.$ (Source: my own)

So far, my attempt was to express the equation as a quadratic in $c$:
$c^2 + (2b - b^2)c + (b^2 -1) = 0,$ and then I used the quadratic formula, which gave me a mess: $c = \frac{b^2 - 2b \pm \sqrt{b^4 -  4b^3 + 4}}{2}.$

So we require $b$ to satisfy $b^4 - 4b^3 + 4$ is a perfect square.

From this state, I'm stuck. Maybe there is another way from the original equation? I am not too sure how to solve this problem.

Any help is appreciated,

Comment: Since the equation is cubic, I wouldn't be surprised if some [elliptic curves theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve) was required to find the solutions.

Comment: That's a good start. You know that expression is a perfect square, so bound it between 2 consecutive perfect squares for all but finitely many values of $b$.

Comment: @jjagmath  it's inequalities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that for all but finitely many values, we can bound $b^4-4b^3 + 4$ between 2 consecutive perfect squares.

> $(b^2-2b-3)^2 < b^4 - 4b^3 +4 < (b^2 - 2b - 2)^2$

Note: The square on the right when expanded starts off as $b^4 - 4b^3 + 0 b^2 + \ldots$, which is why it suggests that we test that first. (Or, just work down the list of $(b^2-2b)^2, (b^2 - 2b - 1)^2, \ldots$. )

**Corollary:** The only positive integer solutions arise when $b = 1, 4$.
The only positive integers solutions are $(b, c) = (4, 3), (4, 5)$.

**Followup:** Solve this over the integers.

Comment: Wait the inequality isn't true, but I think I get the idea

Comment: @MaximilianLin Can you elaborate on why the inequality isn't true?

Comment: my bad, I miscalculated something. Your answer is right

Comment: Thanks for the help